# predicting ODE parameters with DiffEqFlux

Tags: neural-network, julia, ode, differentialequations.jl, flux-machine-learning

I'm trying to build a neural network that will take in the solutions to a system of ODE's and predict the parameters of the system. I'm using Julia and in particular, the [DiffEqFlux](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqFlux.jl) package. The structure of a network is a few simple `Dense` layers chained together that predict some intermediate parameters (in this case, some chemical reaction free energies), which then feed into some deterministic (non-trained) layers that convert those parameters into the ones that go into the system of equations (in this case, reaction rate constants). I've tried two different approaches from here:

1. Chain the ODE solve directly on as the last layer of the network. In this case, the loss function is just comparing the inputs to the outputs.
2. Have the ODE solve in the loss function, so the network output is just the parameters.

However, in neither case can I get `Flux.train!` to actually run.

A silly little example for the first option that gives the same error I'm getting (I've tried to keep as many things parallel to my actual case as possible, i.e. the solver, etc., although I did omit the intermediate deterministic layers since they don't seem to make a difference) is shown below.

```
using Flux, DiffEqFlux, DifferentialEquations

# let's use Chris' favorite example, Lotka-Volterra
function lotka_volterra(du,u,p,t)
  x, y = u
  α, β, δ, γ = p
  du[1] = dx = α*x - β*x*y
  du[2] = dy = -δ*y + γ*x*y
end
u0 = [1.0,1.0]
tspan = (0.0,10.0)

# generate a couple sets of solutions to train on
training_params = [[1.5,1.0,3.0,1.0], [1.4,1.1,3.1,0.9]]
training_sols = [solve(ODEProblem(lotka_volterra, u0, tspan, tp)).u[end] for tp in training_params]

model = Chain(Dense(2,3), Dense(3,4), p -> diffeq_adjoint(p, ODEProblem(lotka_volterra, u0, tspan, p), Rodas4())[:,end])

# in this case we just want outputs to match inputs
# (actual parameters we're after are outputs of next-to-last layer)
training_data = zip(training_sols, training_sols)

# mean squared error loss
loss(x,y) = Flux.mse(model(x), y)

p = Flux.params(model[1:2])

Flux.train!(loss, p, training_data, ADAM(0.001))
# gives TypeError: in typeassert, expected Float64, got ForwardDiff.Dual{Nothing, Float64, 8}
```

I've tried all three solver layers, `diffeq_adjoint`, `diffeq_rd`, and `diffeq_fd`, none of which work, but all of which give different errors that I'm having trouble parsing.

For the other option (which I'd actually prefer, but either way would work), just replace the model and loss function definitions as:

```
model = Chain(Dense(2,3), Dense(3,4))

function loss(x,y)
   p = model(x)
   sol = diffeq_adjoint(p, ODEProblem(lotka_volterra, u0, tspan, p), Rodas4())[:,end]
   Flux.mse(sol, y)
end
```

The same error is thrown as above.

I've been hacking at this for over a week now and am completely stumped; any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're running into https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqFlux.jl/issues/31, i.e. forward-mode AD for the Jacobian doesn't play nice with Flux.jl right now. To get around this, use `Rodas4(autodiff=false)` instead.

Comment: When I put that option in, I get `Warning: dt <= dtmin. Aborting. There is either an error in your model specification or the true solution is unstable.`

However, if I just take the output directly and call the solver in the REPL (with exactly the same signature as I'm using in my layer definition), it works fine...

Comment: It might mean that the adjoint call is diverging. Maybe decrease the tolerances, and start with a smaller time span to learn on? At least, this is now just playing with the training process to get a convergent training system, and not a general issue.

Comment: What I can't figure out is why it works perfectly when I just pull the output directly and run the solve separately (using `diffeq_adjoint`), but it doesn't work when it's chained into the network. Can you give me any hints about what might be different between those two cases? I'm running out of ideas for threads to pull on here...thanks again!